# c# What's the difference in these child class instances with an abstract base class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I don't know how to phrase this question properly, but I can't seem to find a similar question on StackOverflow

Say I have a abstract base class `A` and a child class `B`.

Apparently I can create the child object via both of these lines

```
A child = new B();

B child = new B();
```

And it seems like they support the same usage of methods.

What's the difference?

Comment: A `B` is neccessarily an `A`. It has everything `A` has, and possibly more. If you added extra methods or properties in `B` that are not defined in `A`, you would not be able to use them if you treat your variable as an `A`. You would have to cast it back to a `B`.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, ahhh make sense. I think the reason this came up was because I currently don't have any extra public methods in my child class, so A and B are technically supporting the same set of methods :)

Comment: @ygongdev Thats pretty typical. What usually changes between child classes is the *implementation* not the *interface*

Answer (score 0):

Since `B` derives from `A`, `B` **is** `A`, thus you can set an instance of `B` to a reference typed as `A`.

That is, a `B` instance set to a reference of type `A` will be able to access members of `A` but not from `B`. This is an *upcast* (casting a reference from more to less typed).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the `B` instance is automatically down casted (as described on page 136 of the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)) to be of reference type `A`. This means available methods to call will be those found in `A`. Note that these might be *fewer* than those found in `B`. However, all *abstract* methods needs to be implemented by `B`.

For example, let `B` be defined like to

```
class abstract A
{
    public abstract void Foo();
}

class B
{
    public override void Foo() {}
    public void Bar() {}
}
```

Here the method `Bar()` will only be available in your second case - `var B = new B ();`

Note that if you use the `var` keyword, an expression e.g. `new B()` will be of type `B`.

Comment: This is exactly where my curiosity was sparked. Apparently if I do `var A = new B()`; A can also access `Bar()` Which I guess kinda of made sense to me

Comment: Yes, very attentive! This is because the `var` keyword will interfere the type from the right hand expression, namely `new B()`. The type of this expression is `B` and hence, the variable `A` will be of type `B` despite its name.

Comment: However, if you do `A a = new B();` you will find that the `Bar()` method is no longer accessible.

Comment: Oh, but actually if I did A = new B() (without var), I can still access Bar()

Comment: Yes, if A is of type `B` you can

Comment: Sorry, got confused. I've updated my example. Now the `Bar` method is in `B`. This should be a more helpful example.

Answer (score 0):

B can do everything A can do, but B can do more - whatever was defined in the child class is available to B (but not to A).

By assigning a B to an A variable, you (temporarily) remove this, and now it can do only what an A can do (until you assign it back to a B variable).

Comment: B cannot necessarily do more - They might be able to do the same things. :)

Comment: Yes, if you create a subclass with nothing in it. Not very useful, but borderline possible.